# Associated gocd agent to a pipeline group

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, go-cd, thoughtworks-go

I have 5 `gocd agents` connected to my `gocd` server.

The use-case is I want to run a particular pipeline belonging to a particular `pipeline group` to a specific go-agent every time.

Example: all pipelines having `pipeline-group-1` should run on agent `agent-4`.

Can we achieve this using GOCD?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environments feature for that, though you have to put each pipeline in the group into that environment. I don't think there is a group-wide feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can mainly use a certain agent as a resource in your Jobs this makes sure that you could run the pipeline via the same agent